# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, React

Tags: reactjs

I have such `jsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const RowComponent = ({ rowList, personToFind }) => 
  <Grid.Row columns={3} centered>
    {rowList.map(person =>
      <Grid.Column key={person.id}>
        <ImageComponent person={person} personToFind={personToFind} />
      </Grid.Column>)
    }   
  </Grid.Row>

const GamePage = React.memo(({ peopleList }) => {
  const randomPeopleList = getNRandomItems(peopleList, 6)
  
  const topRow = randomPeopleList.slice(0, 3)
  const bottomRow = randomPeopleList.slice(3)
  const personToFind = getRandomItem(randomPeopleList)
  
  return (
    <Grid>
      <RowComponent rowList={topRow} personToFind={personToFind} />
      <RowComponent rowList={bottomRow} personToFind={personToFind} />
    </Grid>
  ) 
})
```

The error says to `Check the render method of RowComponent`. I tried putting `key` on `Grid.Row`, `RowComponent` and `ImageComponent` (and `Image` that is within it). Nothing of that is working, so I am confused as to where should I put key. According to the thread:

[Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153873/warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop)

It should be outermost element, but I put it on the outermost `Grid.Row`, `RowComponent` itself and it still shows.. I verified that `person.id` is unique `id`.

> Update

There are two errors of the same type. The first one is:

[image]

I eliminated it by generating `key` differently for the `Grid.Column`:

```
const RowComponent = ({ rowList, personToFind }) => 
  <Grid.Row columns={3} centered>
    {rowList.map((person, idx) =>
      <Grid.Column key={`column-${idx}-img-${person.id}`}>
        <ImageComponent person={person} personToFind={personToFind} />
      </Grid.Column>)
    }   
  </Grid.Row>
```

I don't understand why this is needed though since each `person.id` is unique. Another error still persists:

[image]

Comment: It must be on the outermost element __of the array__ you're generating, this is `Grid.Column` in your case.

Comment: You placed your key correctly. There is probably another component that you forgot to add a key to. Search for ".map(" and check if all mapped outermost components have the key defined

Comment: im damm sure `<ImageComponent key={Math.random()} />`

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Just updated the ticket. Tried `Math.random()` on `Image` and `ImageComponent` - not working.

Comment: Never use `Math.random()` with a key or you’ll get very bad react performance. If you don’t have a unique id for each element, at worst, use an increased index.

Comment: Its just for testing, to guarantee that its unique. Of course, I am always trying to use some key that is relevant to my current UI.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const RowComponent = ({ rowList, personToFind }) => 
  <Grid.Row columns={3} centered>
    {rowList.map((person,index) =>
      <Grid.Column key={person.id+""+index}>
        <ImageComponent person={person} personToFind={personToFind} />
      </Grid.Column>)
    }   
  </Grid.Row>

const GamePage = React.memo(({ peopleList }) => {
  const randomPeopleList = getNRandomItems(peopleList, 6)
  
  const topRow = randomPeopleList.slice(0, 3)
  const bottomRow = randomPeopleList.slice(3)
  const personToFind = getRandomItem(randomPeopleList)
  
  return (
    <Grid>
      <RowComponent rowList={topRow} personToFind={personToFind} />
      <RowComponent rowList={bottomRow} personToFind={personToFind} />
    </Grid>
  ) 
})
```

```
{rowList.map((person,index) =>
      <Grid.Column key={person.id+" "+index}>
        <ImageComponent person={person} personToFind={personToFind} />
      </Grid.Column>)
    }
```

The reason behind using key={person.id+" "+index} is , key should be as much unique as it can be .
what if you have same person.id with two or more child ?
To handle such test cases , we are doing that key = {person.id+" "+index}