# how to come up with a good key for my map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm having a really hard time coming up with a key it gives me an error and I can't figure it out. I've tried giving the unique id to the div with the class artist  here's what one data object that's being displayed looks like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Hypervenom Phinish 'Volt'",
  price: "200",
  SizinginNumbers: true,
  img: "https://image.goat.com/transform/v1/attachments/product_template_pictures/images/013/255/557/original/749901_703.png.png?action=crop&width=950",
  color: "#cfeb30",
  size: null,
  itemcolor: null,
  catagory: "soccer",
  quantity:1
},
```

this is the where the data is being mapped out the cart is is a state that im using to store the data in.

```
<div className="cart">
            <h1>your Cart </h1>
            <h3>you have :{cart.length} item(s) </h3>
            {

            
            
            
            cart.map((item) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <ul  className="cartlist" style={{backgroundColor:item.color}}>
                    <li className="cartitem">x</li>

                    <li className="cartitem">
                      <img className="cartimgs" src={item.img} alt="" />
                    </li>
                    <li className="cartitem">{item.title}</li>
                    <li className="cartitem">Size: {item.size}</li>
                    <li className="cartitem">price: ${item.price}</li>

                    <button className="quantitybtn">-</button>
                    <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                    <button className="quantitybtn">+</button>
                  </ul>
                </>
              );
            })}


          </div>
```

here is the error i get
:[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `<ul key={item.id}...`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153873/warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop

Comment: Note that the key must go on the outermost element. Right now, that's a fragment, using the shorthand syntax. Fragments must use the longhand syntax to have a key, as in `<React.Fragment key={item.id}>`. You could also delete the fragment, making the `ul` the outermost element, and then put the key on there like @Andy suggests.

Comment: well the problem is that a user can click on the same item multipe times there for i can pick the exact same item and react wont know how to update it since its the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a key prop to your component (HTML), <></> don't support key or any other attribute to it as prop, so use React.fragment

```
<div className="cart">
  <h1>your Cart </h1>
  <h3>you have :{cart.length} item(s) </h3>
  {
    cart.map((item) => {
    return (
    <React.fragment key={index}>
      <ul className="cartlist" style={{backgroundColor:item.color}}>
        <li className="cartitem">x</li>

        <li className="cartitem">
          <img className="cartimgs" src={item.img} alt="" />
        </li>
        <li className="cartitem">{item.title}</li>
        <li className="cartitem">Size: {item.size}</li>
        <li className="cartitem">price: ${item.price}</li>

        <button className="quantitybtn">-</button>
        <span>{item.quantity}</span>
        <button className="quantitybtn">+</button>
      </ul>
    </React.fragment>
    );
  })}


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple just remove react fragment and add key to ul element. If you don't have unique id, map function have  index in second parameter.

```
<div className="cart">
            <h1>your Cart </h1>
            <h3>you have :{cart.length} item(s) </h3>
            {

            cart.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                  <ul key={index}  className="cartlist" style={{backgroundColor:item.color}}>
                    <li className="cartitem">x</li>

                    <li className="cartitem">
                      <img className="cartimgs" src={item.img} alt="" />
                    </li>
                    <li className="cartitem">{item.title}</li>
                    <li className="cartitem">Size: {item.size}</li>
                    <li className="cartitem">price: ${item.price}</li>

                    <button className="quantitybtn">-</button>
                    <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                    <button className="quantitybtn">+</button>
                  </ul>
              );
            })}


          </div>
```