# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: next.js

nextjs13.1 The key problem is prompted, but the format is unknown. Many similar answers have been searched, but this presentation method does not seem to be found. Is there a good way to solve it? A warning appears on the console:

```
next-dev.js?3515:20 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Links`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at li
    at Links
    at div
    at footer
    at Footer
    at div
    at Home
    at PersistGate (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/redux-persist/es/integration/react.js:39:5)
    at Provider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:13:3)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:21:11)
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:62:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:301:63)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:850:919)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:62:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:172:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:347:11)
```

This is my code from nextjs13.1. Please help me. How should I add key to this writing format：

```
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Links() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.footer_links}>
      {
        links.map((link, i) =>(
          <ul>
            {
              i ===0 ? (
              <img src="../images/logo.png" alt="" />
              ) : (
                    <b>{link.heading}</b>
              )}
            {
              link.links.map((link) =>(
                <li>
                  <Link href={link.link}>{link.name}</Link>
                </li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const links = [
  {
    heading: "SHOPPAY",
    links: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "About us",
        link: "/about",
      },
      {
        name: "Contact us",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "Social Responsibility",
        link: "",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    heading: "HELP & SUPPORT",
    links: [
      {
        name: "Shipping Info",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "Returns",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "How To Order",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "How To Track",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "Size Guide",
        link: "",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    heading: "CUSTOMER SERVICE",
    links: [
      {
        name: "Customer service",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "Terms and Conditions",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "Consumers(Transactions)",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "Take our feedback survey",
        link: "",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153873/warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React requires every element in a loop like `map` to have a `key` prop with a unique value, like an ID. In your case, both `map` functions need to define a `key` on the returned parent element.

If your ID keys are incremented numbers, they should also be avoided since these IDs are not globally unique.

---

Typically the index `i` shouldn't be used for the `key`, but in your case, another unique string isn't defined for every item.

```js
links.map((link, i) =>(
 <ul key={`link-${i}`}>
  {link.links.map((link, i) =>(
    <li key={`sublink-${i}`}>...</li>
  ))}
 </ul>
))
```

A best-case scenario is that you globally unique IDs defined for each link, and the ID is used as the keys.

```js
links.map((link) =>(
 <ul key={link.id}>
  {link.links.map((link) =>(
    <li key={link.id}>...</li>
  ))}
 </ul>
))
```